# Table showing on new page

Tags: floats, positioning, page-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I have the following problem, I started a new section with appendix and I put a few tables there. But tables are not displayed right after heading but there are displaying from some reason on the new page

```
\subsection{Datové slovníky}

Zde se nacházejí datové slovníky ke všem tabulkám v databázi.
\nopagebreak
%this table is displayed on the new page
\begin{table}
    \small\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}        
    \centering
    \caption{Datový slovník tabulky Project}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Název & Typ & Velikost & Klíč & Index & Null & Popis \\
    \hline
    id & integer & - & Ano & Ano & Ne & ID projektu \\
    \hline
    name & varchar & 100 & Ne & Ne & Ne & Název projektu \\
   \end{tabular}
   \label{fig:project}
\end{table}
```

I really cant figure this out, table is nor too wide or high, so I dont get it. I am using document class defined by my university teacher (I am writing bachelor thesis)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: The `table` environment is an example of a `float`. *Study* [keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned) and the links within, and comment back with progress or follow-up questions :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I tried it only with `[!h]`, I didn't know that I should use all types of floats